# Qt calendarWidget selection issue/ Python3.9 and PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a calendar widget and a counter, based on the number of clicks, the date chosen will be reflected in label. When I didnt click anything, the calendar already chose the default date which is the current date, so the current date cannot be clicked, i have to move the cursor and back to it if i need the current date, but I already have label to record number of clicks and moving the cursor and click will be count as click1, so in this case, in label1 the date chosen either date other than the current or if i want the current, it will be count as click2 and record the date in label2

```
 self.calendarWidget.selectionChanged.connect(self.update)
 
def update(self):
    self.calander+=1
   
    if  self.calander==1:
        
        dateSelected = self.calendarWidget.selectedDate().toPyDate()
        self.PCD1.setText(str(dateSelected))
       
    elif self.calander==2:
       
        dateSelected = self.calendarWidget.selectedDate().toPyDate()
        self.PCD2.setText(str(dateSelected))
    elif self.calander==3:
        dateSelected = self.calendarWidget.selectedDate().toPyDate()
        self.PCD3.setText(str(dateSelected))
    elif self.calander==4:
        dateSelected = self.calendarWidget.selectedDate().toPyDate()
        self.PCD4.setText(str(dateSelected))
```

Comment: You could set the current date to an arbitrary date in the past *before* connecting the signal, and then call `setCurrentPage()` with the current year and month.